# C++ Program just pops up with press any key to continue

Tags: visual-c++

im pretty new to c++ and my program wont do what its supposed to do, just pop up with press any key to continue. Im using visual c++. heres the code:

```
#include "ex311.h"

void ex311::main
{
 double principle, rate, interest;
 int days;
 Scanner *sc = new Scanner(System::in);
 std::cout << std::wstring(L"Enter principle (-1 to end):  ");
 principle = sc->nextDouble();
 while (principle != -1)
 {
  std::cout << std::wstring(L"Enter annual interest rate (as a decimal):  ");
  rate = sc->nextDouble();
  std::cout << std::wstring(L"Enter number of days:  ");
  days = sc->nextInt();
  interest = principle * rate / 365 * days;
  printf(L"Interest is %.2f\n", interest);
  std::cout << std::wstring(L"\nEnter principle (-1 to end):  ");
  principle = sc->nextDouble();
 }
}
```

And heres the scanner class

```
#pragma once

#include <string>
#include <iostream>

class ex311
{
 static void main;
};
```

Comment: I'm not sure how does it compile at all... Because it's a Java code, not C++...

Comment: Sorry, posted the wrong code. just fixed it.

Comment: no where in this code does it show where it would popup a message, perhaps your Scanner class does this, in which case we'll need to see it

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're trying to code in Java-way (as I see Java's Scanner class which allocated on heap and wasn't properly disposed).

First of all, paste here all the code. I think the problem is that there is already another main function, defined in a global scope.

You need to find main() function in other files and remove it. Then replace

```
void ex311::main(std::wstring args[])
```

With

```
void main()
```

Comment: Ok, did that, and still just getting a popup with press any key to continue.

Comment: @user2933941 have you found main() function in other files?

Comment: @user2933941 are you sure? I'm afraid, you've used new project wizard, which creates default entry point (main, _tmain or wmain) like win32 console application, not empty project. Check your solution explorer for any other file.